# Proximo HTTP proxy vs SOCKS proxy

Tags: heroku, squid, proximo

Does Proximo provide both a SOCKS proxy (using Dante) and a HTTP proxy (using something like Squid?).

Background: I'm think of using proximo to whitelist my Heroku app for a SOAP connection to a financial data provider. I know Proximo can wrap all traffic through a SOCKS proxy (using Dante and socksify), but does the service use a separate proxy for HTTP/HTTPS traffic (like a Squid HTTP proxy?). I don't want to socksify all my traffic if I don't have to.

Comment: Maybe relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21886916/17339